# Minimum number of rows where the column sum is as close to N, dealing with non-integers

Tags: python, pandas, algorithm, math, data-structures

I've got a DataFrame that looks something like this in Pandas.

```
|  clip_id |   duration |
|---------:|-----------:|
|     0050 |    3.085   |
|     0019 |    3.125   |
|     0001 |    3.265   |
...
|     0010 |    4.47    |
|     0024 |    4.48    |
|     0034 |    4.49    |
|     0004 |    4.515   |
...
|     0008 |    6.795   |
|     0034 |    6.99    |
|     0026 |    6.995   |
...
|     0004 |    9.005   |
|     0024 |    9.185   |
|     0048 |    9.265   |
|     0029 |   10.055   |
|     0001 |   10.255   |
|     0006 |   10.85    |
```

I've trimmed the table here using ellipses, but the number of rows is usually around between 30 and 100. Also I have sorted the table using the `duration` column.

My goal is to find the minimum number of clips such that their sum is lazily above some value *N*. In other words, if *N*=25, picking up the bottom three rows is not a good enough solution, as the sum there would be 31.16 and there exists a greedier/lazier solution which is closer to 25.

It's been a super long time since I've taken an algorithms / data-structures class but I was sure there was a Heap-related solution to this problem. I also haven't done dynamic programming in Python before but perhaps there's a solution which involves DP. Looking around at other solved questions on StackOverflow, the most voted answers always assume that

(A) you're dealing with integers, OR

(B) you'll be able to find an exact sum

But that won't be the case for what I'm trying to do. Ideally if I can do this while the data is stored in a Pandas DataFrame, then it'll be easy to return the `clip_id` values for those resultant rows.

Appreciate any and all help I can get on this front!

**Edit**: So thinking about the problem more, what makes it tough is that there are two competing goals: I want the fewest number of rows, but I also want the sum barely above *N* if possible. So between the two goals, I would say being as close to *N* is the more important condition. So for example, if increasing the number of rows by 2 can bring the total closer to >= N, then that would be more preferred.

Answer (score 0):

Is the solution below something that you meant? Do you want to get the rows more than N or you want to exclude them? According to your answer, I can update the code.

```
def min_num_rows(data, threshold):
   for i in range(1, len(data)):
      if data[-i:]['duration'].sum() > threshold:
         data = data[: -i]
         break
      else:
         continue
   return data[-i: ]
df = df.sort_values('duration', ascending = True)
above = min_num_rows(df, 25)
```